# Seleccionar dos últimas palabras en una lista

Tags: r, select, split

Tengo un data.frame con nombres de especies. Delante de los nombres de las especies, hay una serie de códigos que quiero quitar. El problema es que no siempre tienen el mismo número de caractéteres ni hay el mismo número de códigos. Me quiero quedar con las dos últimas palabras: "Dismorphia_spio", "Colias_paleno"...

```
NW153_23_Dismorphia_spio
MM03233_Colias_palaeno
NW151_2_Anthocharis_cardamine
MM06585_Pieris_rapae
NW149_4_Aporia_crataegi
PM03_14_Curetis_barsine
EW28_1_Celastrina_neglecta
MM04799_Favonius_quercus
NW84_13_Hamearis_lucina
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Si el criterio es *"Me quiero quedar con las dos últimas palabras"*, podemos usar patrones regulares para "capturar" estas dos últimas palabras:

```
x <- c('NW153_23_Dismorphia_spio MM03233_Colias_palaeno', 
'NW151_2_Anthocharis_cardamine',
'MM06585_Pieris_rapae',
'NW149_4_Aporia_crataegi', 
'PM03_14_Curetis_barsine EW28_1_Celastrina_neglecta', 
'MM04799_Favonius_quercus NW84_13_Hamearis_lucina')

proto <- data.frame(nombres=character())
strcapture('^.*_(\\w+_\\w+)$', x, proto)

                nombres
1        Colias_palaeno
2 Anthocharis_cardamine
3          Pieris_rapae
4       Aporia_crataegi
5   Celastrina_neglecta
6       Hamearis_lucina
```

`strcapture()` procesa un vector `x` mediante un patrón regular de captura y retorna un `data.frame` con la estructura definida en `proto`. Por el lado del patrón `^.*_(\\w+_\\w+)$` básicamente se define la captura de las dos últimas palabras (`\\w`) separadas por un guión bajo desde el final (`$`).